# Showing filesystem in QTreeWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qtreewidget

I have a simple Question.
I want to show my filesystem in a QTreeWidget just like an common file explorer.

How can i achieve that? I guess searching through all files and add them manual is not the approach to chose, right?

Comment: See [QFileSystemModel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qfilesystemmodel.html).

Comment: QFileSystemModel + QTree_View_ (not QTreeWidget)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use QDirModel and QTreeView instead of QTreeWidget,
here is a code snippet:

```
QDirModel *model = new QDirModel;
QTreeView *tree = new QTreeView(splitter);  
tree->setModel(model);  
tree->setRootIndex(model->index("C:\\"));
```

Comment: ok i guess i experiment a little bit more since i cannot find a "good" tutorial on this QT Widgets but thanks anyway

Comment: You should note that the docs state `The usage of QDirModel is not recommended anymore. The QFileSystemModel class is a more performant alternative.`.

Comment: Is there a way to set on click handlers for the items in a pure QTreeView? I only find solutions for QTreeWidget